# Problems inserting a record into mongoDB Next.js 13.3 and User Schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, next.js13

I have a problem that I can save a record created by a schema from Mongoose (User) to the database. I get the error below. Does the whole thing work at all with monoose and MongoDB Client together with Next.js?

app/models/User/page.tsx

```
import { Schema, model, models } from "mongoose";

const userSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
email: {
 type: String,
 required: true,
 unique: true,
 },
});

const User = models.User || model("User", userSchema);

export default User;
```

app/api/generate/route.ts

```
 export async function POST(request:Request )
{

 const client = await clientPromise;
 const db = client.db("generate");

 console.log('CREATING DOCUMENT');
 db.collection("singleUser").insertOne( await new 
 User({name:"Benij",email:"max.mustermann@gmx.de"}))
 console.log('CREATING DONE');
```

next.config

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
 webpack: (config) => {
// this will override the experiments
 config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true };
 // this will just update topLevelAwait property of config.experiments
 // config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true
 return config;
},
reactStrictMode: true,
 images: {
remotePatterns: [
  {
    protocol: "https",
    hostname: "replicate.com",
  },
  {
    protocol: "https",
    hostname: "replicate.delivery",
   },
 ],
},
experimental: {
appDir: true,
 },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

/lib/mongodb.ts

```
 import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

 if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
   throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: 
 "MONGODB_URI"');
 }

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {

 if (!global._mongoClientPromise ) {
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
 }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise;
 } 
else {
 client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
 clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;
```

Error:

> Module not found: Can't resolve 'mongodb-client-encryption' in 'J:\react-projecte\find\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib'

> POST http://localhost:3000/api/generate 500 (Internal Server Error)